.Net 9 Aspire Service Discovery not working
I have created a simple test project with aspire following a few tutorials and the docs online.  and im trying to enable service discovery to get rid of any endpoint addresses in code or config .. i was following the microsoft doc here Doc Link  for the "Implicit discovery by reference" . ive set it up as described and for some reason all thats being passed into my http client is "https+http://api" instead of the environment variable thats supposed to be there.  obv then causes the service to 404.
heres some snippets of the code
AppHost.Program.cs
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 var api = builder.AddProject<Projects.wfd_AlgoliaDemo_api>("api");
var web = builder.AddProject<Projects.wfd_AlgoliaDemo>("wfd-algoliademo")
    .WithReference(api)
    .WithExternalHttpEndpoints();
builder.Build().Run();

And the setup in my frontend app program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AlgoliaService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AlgoliaService>(options =>
{
    var url = "https+http://api";
    options.BaseAddress = new(url);
});

i have double checked in my Service defaults project and the Service discovery is definately enables so im stuck as all the docs and tutorials obv just go "Huzzah it works like magic" ...
any help is appreciated

It does work like magic without any extra code. The starter template already uses service discovery and works fine. Create a new project using the starter template and check what's missing from your code. the environment variable thats supposed that's a different question - where did you specify the environment variable? Aspire doesn't change how .NET Configuration works. Settings can be provided or overridden by environment variables with specific naming

i didnt specify the environment variable thats how aspire compiles the urls and passes them i can see them in the dashboard .. i specify the "api" variable in the apphost and according to the docs thats it ... should work

Updating as well i cant see any difference between my project and a sample aspire it SHOULD work with no issues it just doesnt

That's not what environment variable means. It's the term specified in Wikipedia, used in all OSs. I repeat, Aspire works. All one has to do to prove it is create a new starter project and run it. If you confuse service names with environment variables, it's unclear what your question is in the first place, or whether you even configured the ports of your APIs. You can't use random ports in production (or even development). They'll be blocked by the OS itself, or fail because eg other programs use the same port

BTW a 404 means something is running in that host and port, but the rest of the URL doesn't exist. You didn't post any code that actually calls HttpClient. Are you sure the URLs are correct? Did you check the console output of your service application? Perhaps some other program is already running on that port, blocking your own service? Have you checked the Dashboard?

@panagiotis one of the main points of aspire is to use the service discovery in the way i men tioned above in order to prevent needing to ever actually record the endpoints the docs here state that i dont need to configure them for them to work,  the way that aspire passes these is through environment vars.  The issue ended up being an error that i had incorrectly handled preventing the endpoint from starting and therefore not actually creating the service to then pass into the environment vars

Just to post an answer and close the question the issue was related to an error in build that was not handled correctly causing the service to never create its endpoint, for some reason aspire still thought this was running fine and didnt notify me of any errors.

Did you use?
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

In your project’s program.cs right after creating your builder, make sure you have a reference to servicedefault .NET Aspire project in your API project.
And if you did not have AddServiceDefaults then maybe you need to add to
App.MapDefaultEndpoints();

Before something like Swagger and after app.addRouting().
